# From all those option for traffic filtering what will be the fastest to integrate and develop on windows

Tags: windows, network-programming, monitoring

Hello all
Im searching few weeks now some way to filter and monitor , or just monitor on windows XP and above 
the traffic that goes out and coming in local pc its have to be fast and not heavy resource-consuming , my reason is simple I like to build open source free application 
in the Parental control area .
that not block but just monitor . 
What I find is this I need you humble opinion which do you think will be the easiest and best to implement such thing:

1. LSP layer (fast? )
2. WInCAp
3. NetWork Driver layer using win driver development kit (hard to develop ?)
4. Network Monitor 3.4 ( resource-consuming ?)
5. What else ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: The fastest: A Linux firewall :)